# I wish to resize(grow) my Ubuntu Root partition using GParted [14.04 LTS / Win10 Grub Dual Boot ]

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, format

A long time ago I had allocated only 90 (89.24) GB to my root partition assuming it would be enough for my needs. Alas I now require some space heavy tools like Matlab and larger datasets to process so I would like to add at least 30-50 GB to it. I have a non OS partition which I shrunk on Windows Disk Manager to give me 51.22 GB un-allocatted space.

I have read many GParted related threads but none seem to be an exact duplicate of my situation and as I have broken my bootloader twice this week already after Ubuntu updates, I would like to ask an experienced opinion for the exact steps I must follow, I thus apologize in advance if this an absolute duplicate of the thread(s) I missed.

I understand that to grow a partition, it must have adjacent un-allocated space. I am not sure how to go about moving them safely around. If I simply try to grow the root partition, it says I can only grow it to 91.3 GB (unsure how this number is arrived at either). I realize online partition growing may not be possible, I have a live USB stick ready for this purpose, I feel it would have been more clear if I provided the GParted screenshot from the installed OS.

Here is a screenshot of my GParted:

[image: screenshot]

I would appreciate if you could fill in my lack of concepts as well since I should have been able to figure out the required steps from reading similar posts but could not.

Thank you

Comment: I can give you specific details, but I have some questions first. Do you currently have Windows installed in a dual-boot configuration? If so, which partition is your bootable Windows partition? sda4? What is sda6 used for, data? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and a Windows install/repair disc?

Comment: Windows is dualbooted via Grub with Windows 10 installed in sd4, UEFI with secure boot disabled. 

sda6 is a data partition where I keep most media files that I can use in both Windows/Ubuntu, it was this partition that I shrunk in Windows. 

I have access to Ubuntu Live USB, Windows repair disc and Linux Boot Repair USB. 

Thank you for the reply

Comment: Please see my partial answer. Report back.

Comment: Hello, I carried out the tests, they were all successful. (Changed to hand cursors for all the mentioned partitions, swapon/swapoff was successful)

Comment: Whatis sda8 for? It's `ext4`, but has no mountpoint assigned and seems to be nearly empty. If you mount sda8 (`sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt`) and then move the data from `/mnt` somewhere else (there is enough space left in `/`), then stop swap space (`sudo swapoff-a`) and modify `/etc/fstab` not to use swap, you might delete sda8 and sda10 and increase sda9 into the unused space.

Comment: @ridgy : Good point let me look into that, will get back to you, seems like a random partition, but I don't remember it being visible on either Windows or Ubuntu file browsers.

Comment: Please do step #2. If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ridgy don't delete swap.

Comment: OK. After perhaps deleting sda8, OP could  do `swapoff`, move sda10 to the right, and then do `swapon`. Would give enough free space anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to move sda6, sda5, sda8 and sda10 to the right, in that order, and then resize sda9 to add 51GiB to it. Please note that moving/resizing partitions **can** result in data corruption/loss. Hence my next statement...

## Backup important data on the effected partitions sda8 and sda6!

## Step #1

Let's do a test first...

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda10 in the bottom pane and select `swapoff`

---

- right-click on sda6 in the lower pane and select `move/resize`
- in the graphic upper pane, hover the mouse pointer over the center of sda6 and note how the cursor changes to a hand cursor
- in the graphic upper pane, hover the mouse pointer over the right side of sda6 and note how the cursor changes to an arrow cursor
- close/cancel the `move/resize` window without making any changes

---

- right-click on sda10 in the lower pane and select `move/resize`
- hover the mouse pointer over sda10 in the graphic in the upper pane
- does the cursor change to a hand cursor?
- close/cancel the `move/resize` window without making any changes

---

- right-click on sda5 in the lower pane and select `move/resize`
- hover the mouse pointer over sda5 in the graphic in the upper pane
- does the cursor change to a hand cursor?
- close/cancel the `move/resize` window without making any changes

---

- right-click on sda10 in the bottom pane and select `swapon`

## Step #2

Now lets `move/resize` some partitions...

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda10 in the bottom pane and select `swapoff`

---

- for each of sda6, sda5, sda8, and sda10 partitions, in that order...

  - right-click on the partition in the lower pane and select `move/resize`
  - use the hand cursor to drag each partition all the way to the right
  - save/close the `move/resize` window
- right-click on sda9 in the lower pane and select `move/resize`
- drag the right edge of sda9 all the way to the right, thereby adding unallocated space to sda9
- save/close the `move/resize` window

---

- right-click on sda10 in the bottom pane and select `swapon`
- done!

Comment: You should point out the downsides and risks of moving the partitions.

Comment: @chaskes statement added... even though I had strongly suggested data backups on sda6/sda8 already.

Comment: Hi this all seems to work and make sense to me,  but since the ETA is massive and I need to leave my office soon, I will try it again later tonight. Sliding the partition markers  myself helped me understand what exactly it is that I need to do, so thank you for that. I have marked your answer as correct but unfortunately my low reputation will not permit a public upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answers the Windows option.

**Log in to Windows**

Open Disk Management or your favorite app (ex. EaseUs) and shrink some memory from Windows partition and leave it as unallocated.

**Log in back to Ubuntu**

After that open GParted and choose your Ubuntu drive. Select "Move/resize" and add this unallocated space to your main Ubuntu partition.(You can format that empty partition before if there looks an error on that partition.)

After these steps it should what you want and you don't become any problem related to corruption or sth. in Windows partition, because this is the process that you did when you install Ubuntu in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the risk-free suggestion but I can't afford to shrink my Windows partition because it's fairly close to full and I will need what's left eventually since I use both Operating systems. This appears to be a valid answer though

Comment: The "Windows option" was handled by the OP when they said... "I have a non OS partition **which I shrunk on Windows Disk Manager** to give me 51.22 GB un-allocatted space." Also, you can't use gparted on a mounted file system.